# Javascript Relative Time - Display difference in Years & Months

Tags: javascript

Have been fighting this for too many days.  I am trying to display the difference of a date (x) and now as follows:

1. If the diff is exactly a year or years - just display the year diff
2. If the diff is years and months (1 year, 5 months) display it like that
3. If the diff is months (no years), display the months diff
4. If it's days, display the days.

Hope that's clear - I'm very tired.

Here is my code (the commented lines are what I can't get to work):

```
function RelativeTime(x){
    var plural = '';

    var mins = 60, hour = mins * 60; day = hour * 24,
    week = day * 7, month = week * 4, year = day * 365;

if (x >= year){ x = (x / year)|0; dformat="year"; }
//else
//if ((x >= year)&& (x >= month)) { x = (x / year), (x / month)|0 ; dformat="year" , "month"; }
else if (x >= month) { x = (x / month)|0; dformat="month"; }
else if (x >= day*4) { x = (x / day)|0; dformat="day"; }
else if (x >= hour) { x = (x / hour)|0; dformat="hr"; }
else if (x >= mins) { x = (x / mins)|0; dformat="min"; }
else { x |= 0; dformat="sec"; }
if (x > 1) plural = 's';
if (x < 0) x = 0;
return x + ' ' + dformat + plural;
}
```

Comment: What is fed into `RelativeTime()`, can you give us a sample `x` ?

Comment: variables are passed.  In a nutshell, what I am doing is finding the join age of all team members.

Answer (score 2):

Try, this http://jsfiddle.net/mk95J/5/:

```
var age = '';

function RelativeTime(x){
    var ymwdhm = [ [31536000, 'year'],
                   [2419200, 'month'],
                   [604800, 'week'],
                   [86400, 'day'],
                   [3600, 'hour'],
                   [60, 'min'],
                   [1, 'sec'] ];

    for(var i=0;i<7;i++) {
        if(x >= ymwdhm[i][0]) {
            var res = parseInt(x / ymwdhm[i][0], 10);
            age += res;
            age += ymwdhm[i][1];
            age += res > 1 ? 's ' : ' '; // plural

            RelativeTime(x - (res * ymwdhm[i][0]));
            break;
        }
    }
}

RelativeTime( 35746121 );
document.write(age);  // 1year 1month 2weeks 6days 17hours 28mins 41 secs
```

Answer (score 0):

I would think you would want to construct your string as you go, since you want to build it up. The "else if" constructs would be good if you were only going to show the highest level of difference (only years, or only months).

Maybe something like this:

```
function RelativeTime(x) {


    var mins = 60, hour = mins * 60; day = hour * 24,
         week = day * 7, month = week * 4, year = day * 365;


    var responseString = '';

    if (x >= year) {
      var numberOfYears = parseInt(x / year, 10);
      x = x - (numberOfYears * year);
      responseString += numberOfYears + ' year';
      if (numberOfYears > 1) {
          responseString += 's';
      }
      responseString += ' ';
    }

    if (x >= month) {
      var numberOfMonths = parseInt(x / month, 10);
      x = x - (numberOfMonths * month);
      responseString += numberOfMonths + ' month';
      if (numberOfMonths > 1) {
          responseString += 's';
      } 
      responseString += ' ';
    }
    return responseString;
}

// And so on ....

document.write(RelativeTime(35746121));
```

There are some efficiencies that could be managed within there as well (it's certainly looking like a function could come out of there to replace the almost duplicate code, and you could probably reuse some variables through there).

Comment: I think the issue is that I have trying to do both the high level and the (year, months)

Comment: Let me try to be clearer...  If the member joined 3/10/2010, the diff is 1 year.  BUT if the member joined 1/10/2010, then the diff is 1 Year, 2 Months

Comment: and the display is set up like this row += '<td class="age">'+ RelativeTime(json.joined) + '</td>';

Comment: I edited my response to show the whole workflow and correct a couple typos. It's essentially a more verbose version of what erikb posted, and from your description, it does what you need. The response on this one is 1 year 1 month. If the extra code was added, it would keep going.